# Password prompt before OS is boot

Tags: bootcamp, password, efi

My Macbook previous OS is Mavericks,one day, i use find my iphone to lock my macbook and the Computer started to prompt me enter password(not the lock my mac Firmware password, i removed it right after the first Firmware password prompt) before the OS start to boot(It's like asking for password on BIOS if it were a PC).Then i upgraded to Yosemite and it's no longer ask me for password before system start booting up. The question is how i can get back the old password prompt, or is it just me confusing that the password is prompt before system start.

Comment: "Then i upgraded to Yosemite and it's no longer ask me for password before system start booting up.” The firmware password? Is Filevault enabled?

Comment: The EFI i mention is firmware. The password is same as the login password i normally uses.Also the interface look the same to me, just like the one i would enter when i login after the computer goes to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

**To re-enable an EFI password:**

1. Boot into Recovery holding <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at the startup chime
2. From the menu bar, select **Utilities > Firmware Password Utility**
3. Enter a Firmware password and quit the Utility pane.

Note that you’ll only be prompted for this EFI password if you attempt to boot the machine [**differently than you would normally**](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255). Otherwise, you’ll boot directly into OS X at startup without being prompted for the EFI password.

**To re-enable a login password:**

Open System Preferences.

1. Select **Users & Groups > Login Options > Automatic Login: OFF**